# Switch works for a specific case but only on certain items?

Tags: php, switch-statement

I'm having an odd issue with a switch I've created:

```
<?php
$stream = $row->field_stream;
 $img = "";
  switch ( $stream ) {
  case 'Landfill':
    $img = 'landfill.gif';
    break;
  case 'Paper (Blue Box)':
    $img = 'paper-blue-box.gif';
    break;
  case 'Scrap Metal ':
    $img = 'scrap-metal.gif';
    break;
  case 'Household Hazardous Waste Depot':
    $img = 'hazardous-waste-depot.gif';
    break;
  case 'Container Recycling (Yellow Bin)':
    $img = 'yellow-bin-recycling.gif';
    break;
  case 'Regular Garbage (Bag/Can) ':
    $img = 'regular-garbage-can.gif';
    break;
  case 'Organics (Green Cart)':
    $img = 'organics-green-cart.gif';
    break;
  case 'Electronic Waste Depot':
    $img = 'e-waste-depot.gif';
    break;
  case 'Construction & Demolition ':
    $img = 'construction-demo.gif';
    break;
  }
    print '<img class="waste-lookup-icon" src="/sites/default/files/' . $img . '">';
?>
```

It works except for the 'Paper (Blue Box)' case: for some of the items, the switch works and for the others it doesn't. They all have the exact same 'Paper (Blue Box)' value so I'm loosing hair trying to figure out what's going on.

You can see it in action here http://www.ovwrc.com/waste-search if you the search at the top for "Paper", you'll see the image is broken. If you try "Board", you'll see it works for the items that have the 'Paper (Blue Box)' value.

EDIT: FIXED

Thanks for all the help. The issue, as Brian noticed, was that the strings weren't the same even though in the DB they were. Using Search API's "Highlight" feature, it was bolding "Paper" in the string making it different. I added a case for '**Paper**...' and it worked. I could also strip $stream of the  tag but this was an easy fix.

Thanks again!

Comment: Have you tried trimming the value of `$stream` before you apply the `switch` statement?

Comment: I haven't but what would this solve? Do you have an example? Thank you.

Comment: I will suggest you to `var_dump($stream);` before your switch statement. And show us the output.

Comment: an example of trimming can be found on google by `trimming a value php`

Comment: @Ash My guess is that sometimes the value of `$stream` is an exact match (i.e. "Paper (Blue Box)"), but other times it has additional whitespace (i.e. "Paper (Blue Box)  ").

Comment: Is the value of `$stream` same as you would expect? I agree with Brian's comment. Trimming may get you correct image. To check you may do `var_dump($stream===trim($stream))`.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend having a placeholder image rather than leaving an empty string, as the references to the directory alone are coming back with 400 errors.

Comment: Rikesh: I've added `var_dum($string)`. The string(X) is different for the working "Paper (Blue Box)" and the one that doesn't work.

Comment: Brian: great suggestion. I'll create one. If the switch works, I wouldn't need a placeholder but it's a good fallback.

Comment: @Ash It looks like you have two different encodings, since in one case var_dump shows `string(16)` and in another it shows `string(33)`

Comment: Brain, yes I see that now. Is there a way in the switch to refer to both types?

Comment: @Ash From my perspective it's better to treat the cause of a problem (data with different encodings) than it is to treat the effects (non-match in your switch). Can you fix your data?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll, the data has different encoding after it's rendered in a way due to Search API jumping in and highlighting via bolding the search term. In this case, it's Paper. I can either turn off the highlighting, which I don't want to do, add a case that includes the bolding, or strip the <strong> tag from $stream before it's used in the switch function.